# Lattice triangles on 2d

Tags: triangles, coordinate-systems, integers

I'm trying to prove that there exist at least one almost equilateral triangle of  for every error $\epsilon$>0 that has integer coordinates in the Cartesian Plane.

Comment: Please read Wikipedia article section [Almost equilateral  Heronian trinagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heronian_triangle#Almost-equilateral_Heronian_triangles). Note that **all** Heronian triangles can be positioned in the Euclidean plane to have Integer coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part: Take a rational approximation $\frac{p}{q}$ to $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\sin(60°)$, and consider the triangle given by the coordinates $(-q,0),(0,p),(q,0)$. As $\sin$ is continuous,we can get arbritrarily close by increasing the precision of the rational approximation.